# QBSenders didn't send audio and video data

Tags: android, quickblox

i have problem, i use the library of quickblox for android to video chat and   i see in logCat QBDataSenders videoData didn´t send and audiData didn´t send returns true false false

logcat output is

10-15 18:44:08.049: D/tag(1389): videoChatConfigVideoChatConfig[sessionId=1413378829044callType=VIDEO_AUDIOopponentId=1681100isCaller=true
10-15 18:44:08.529: D/tag(1389): videoChatConfigVideoChatConfig[sessionId=1413378841904callType=VIDEO_AUDIOopponentId=1681100isCaller=true
10-15 18:44:08.541: D/com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.objects.QBVideoChat(1389): qbVideoChat.getVideoChatConfig().getOpponentId() == videoChatConfig.getOpponentId()

10-15 18:44:08.543: D/com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.objects.QBVideoChat(1389): videoChatConfig.getSessionId() == null: false

10-15 18:44:08.547: D/tag(1389): videoChatConfigVideoChatConfig[sessionId=1413378841904callType=VIDEO_AUDIOopponentId=1681100isCaller=true

D/QBDataSenders(1389): true false false
10-15 18:46:20.922: D/QBDataSenders(1389): videoData didn`t send

Comment: Please try to be more specific what problem you have. Also post relevant code.

Comment: Hi bro, I am facing same issue. Did you get any solution ??